# How to place more than one view into a variable

Tags: android

So if I have one layout that I would like to apply an animation to, I can do something like:

```
LinearLayout mAnimate;
mAnimate = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
```

And do my stuff with `mAnimate.` But how do get several views into `mAnimate`?

Ie.

```
      LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
      LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);  
     // mAnimate = ??
```

What type should mAnimate have? Is there some array to use?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So if I type mAnimate as an ArrayList, how do I load it with the instances of the layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);  
ArrayList <LinearLayout> myArray;
myArray.add(layout1);
myArray.add(layout2);
```

Comment: Great, I'll try it and let you know. I think this looks right and I'll mark as correct anyway